# Select DOM element w/jQuery created by AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom, jquery-selectors

I think I'm having a "search query terms" problem, as I can't seem to find the correct way to search for this problem, so forgive me if the answer is out there...I *have* been looking :-)

In my simple application, I use AngularJS to load some content from a remote API and then iterate through the results and build a list.  The problem comes in when I'm trying to select some of the elements (checkboxes) that were built by Angular, using jQuery.

How do I target DOM elements with jQuery that were created after page load by Angular?

(I know there may be a more Angular way to do this, but I'm up against my deadline, familiar w/jQuery, and I've given the Angular Way my best shot. Maybe I can fix it later, but right now, I just need to be able to rock this out with.)

Comment: You might need to provide a small example of what you've tried.

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately, I'm so far behind I simply had to remove the feature and move on. I don't (right now) have time to rig up a plnkr or fiddle, but I will do so after I deliver this.

Comment: If you created the list of checkboxes with ng-repeat then there are issues...

Comment: Yes, they were created with ng-repeat because they're not really in the model (yet).  They're checkboxes that will eventually indicate which filed to save and which to ignore.  Still getting around to that fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should understand is that AngularJS elements are jQuery elements so there should be no problem scanning with normal jQuery selectors.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Secondly AngularJS elements have the method find(*some selector*) which is just like the jQuery all selector, so long that you have loaded jQuery prior to loading AngularJS.

If not it will fall back on jQuery lite, packaged with AngularjS, which will only allows you to use find with tag names.

This is the best I can do with the information you provided. Hope it helps.